# How to add/remove an item from Core Data/Table View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data

**Intro:** I'm a beginner in terms of programming and on the way to learn the Swift programming language. I am going through the book and stuck on a few exercises/questions there. Tried to search/implement different methods, but nothing helped.

**The main question:** Basically, that's an app to store some values for a "Book Store" altogether with an assistance of Core Data. Here's the code from ViewController.swift. Currently, I have only one button to add a new book, in a format "My Book" + "books.count".

```
    import UIKit
import CoreData
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var deleteBook: UIBarButtonItem!   
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return loadBooks().count
    }   
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") else { return UITableViewCell() }
        let book: Book = loadBooks()[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = book.title
        return cell
    }
    func loadBooks() -> [Book] {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Book> = Book.fetchRequest()
        var result: [Book] = []
        do {
            result = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            NSLog("My error: %@", error as NSError)
        }
        return result
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext as NSManagedObjectContext
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }  
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var addNew: UIBarButtonItem!  
    @IBAction func addNew(_ sender: Any) {
        let book: Book = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Book", into: managedObjectContext) as! Book
        book.title = "My Book" + String(loadBooks().count)
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("My Error: %@", error)
        }
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }
     @IBAction func deleteBook(_ sender: Any) {

}
}
```

So here's couple of exercises I am trying to do:

1. Add a new view to the app for allowing the user to enter the name of the book
2. Provide a way to remove a book from the list

Comment: If you are beginner to Swift and UIKit and CoreData, I suggest this it is better learn the basics first. I feel you are trying to tackle all 3 at the same time.

Comment: Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

Comment: CoreData: Please learn the basics well, like what is a context, persistent store coordinator etc. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html

Comment: Here's the thing - this step-by-step code was provided in a book with all of the descriptions. By the idea - that's should be solvable, cause this book was created for absolute beginners. I handled previous chapters/exercises and stuck only on those questions. Again - I'm sure, that solutions are very easy and not to mention - the best practice of programming - is actually to write something, even if you don't understand all of the details and it actually works!

Comment: Delete book: `managedObjectContext.performAndWait { managedObjectContext.delete(book) }` If you have the time watch https://itunes.apple.com/podcast/developing-ios-11-apps-with-swift/id1315130780?mt=2

Comment: Tried to wrote it in a method (@IBAction, separate button to delete an entity from a table/list)- didn't help, 2 errors appeared: "Expression resolves to an unused function" and "Use of unresolved identifier 'book'." Perhaps, i added this code to a wrong (?) place

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use `NSFetchedResultsController` with you working with tableView and coreData. For more information and now that how configure it check this link from apple coreData programming learning:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH8-SW1

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just to make it quicker - where should I add this instance (NSFetchedResultsController) simply to ask a user to write a string (name of the book)? Would be glad if you'll answer in detail!

Comment: implement `NSFetchedResultsController` like the link i gave, and in your addNew() method use `let managedObjectContext =  fetchResultController.managedObjectContext` as your `managedObjectContext`

Comment: Tried to initialise a constant right after class VievController -     let fetchResultController:NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, wrote         let managedObjectContext=fetchResultController.managedObjectContext in an addNew method - as a result, I have an error 'Class ViewController' has no initialisers'.

Comment: Updated a comment, check my answer.

Comment: Have you ever checked the link that I gave in the above answer?